# Flask-socketIO + Kafka as a background process

Tags: flask-socketio

### What I want to do

I have an HTTP API service, written in Flask, which is a template used to build instances of different services. As such, this template needs to be generalizable to handle use cases that do and do not include Kafka consumption.

My goal is to have an *optional* Kafka consumer running in the background of the API template. I want any service that needs it to be able to read data from a Kafka topic asynchronously, while also independently responding to HTTP requests as it usually does. These two processes (Kafka consuming, HTTP request handling) aren't related, except that they'll be happening under the hood of the same service.

### What I've written

Here's my setup:

```
# ./create_app.py

from flask_socketio import SocketIO

socketio = None

def create_app(kafka_consumer_too=False):
   """
   Return a Flask app object, with or without a Kafka-ready SocketIO object as well
   """
   app = Flask('my_service')
   app.register_blueprint(special_http_handling_blueprint)

   if kafka_consumer_too:
      global socketio
      socketio = SocketIO(app=app, message_queue='kafka://localhost:9092', channel='some_topic')
      from .blueprints import kafka_consumption_blueprint
      app.register_blueprint(kafka_consumption_blueprint)

      return app, socketio

  return app
```

My run.py is:

```
# ./run.py
from . import create_app
app, socketio = create_app(kafka_consumer_too=True)
if __name__=="__main__":
  socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

And here's the Kafka consumption blueprint I've written, which is where I *think* it should be handling the stream events:

```
# ./blueprints/kafka_consumption_blueprint.py

from ..create_app import socketio

kafka_consumption_blueprint = Blueprint('kafka_consumption', __name__)

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    print('received message: ' + message)
```

### What it currently does

With the above, my HTTP requests are being handled fine when I curl `localhost:5000`. The problem is that, when I write to the `some_topic` Kafka topic (on port 9092), nothing is showing up. I have a CLI Kafka consumer running in another shell, and I can see that the messages I'm sending on that topic *are* showing up. So it's the Flask app that's not reacting: **no messages are being consumed by `handle_message()`**.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are interpreting the meaning of the `message_queue` argument incorrectly.

This argument is used when you have multiple server instances. These instances communicate with each other through the configured message queue. This queue is 100% internal, there is nothing that you are a user of the library can do with the message queue.

If you wanted to build some sort of pub/sub mechanism, then you have to implement the listener for that in your application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Miguel (and for your amazing tutorials and work on Flask-SocketIO!). So I will have different servers running: e.g. a server with the Flask app, which I'd use to consume Kafka messages from a different server (I'm just using localhost:9092 for testing). Right now, my Flask API app can _publish_ Kafka messages to that server - using plain vanilla kafka-python - but, when I tried setting up a KafkaConsumer, the "listening" would hang the entire app and no HTTP requests would process. So I had either/or: either HTTP request handling or Kafka reading.

Comment: Are you using eventlet or gevent? If yes, did you monkey patch the standard library so that it becomes compatible with the greenlet concurrency model used by these frameworks?

Comment: Yep, am using eventlet. No, I didn't monkeypatch. Just tried now and I'm getting something different (different is good?): if I stick `from eventlet import monkey_patch; monkey_patch()` in `/blueprints/kafka_consumption_blueprint.py` or `run.py`, no change (I can receive HTTP but no Kafka). If I put the monkeypatching in `create_app` and try `python3 run.py`, it errors out with `AttributeError: 'KafkaClient' object has no attribute '_closed'`.

Comment: Monkey patching should be done at the top of the main script, run.py in your case. And to avoid weird issues, it should be done above the imports, in line 1 of the script.

Comment: hey so any solution to this? did monkeypatching fix the asyc consumer issue?

Comment: really love to know how to set up a async kafka consumer with normal api for producer, would this require 2 microservices or can this be done in one?